# How to get "data" attribute in ie 7?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-7

I use "data" attribute and in IE7 and I don't know how to get value of it. Can jQuery possibly help me?

I have this

```
window.event.srcElement.getAttribute('data-pk')
```

Of course it does not work.

## Edit:

```
for (i=0; i < max; i++) {

    if (typeof attachEvent == 'undefined'){         
        //open[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){ openSlide(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-pk')), false});
        open[i].onclick = function(e){ openSlide(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-pk')), false};
    } else {
        open[i].attachEvent('onclick', function(){
            openSlide(window.event.srcElement.getAttribute('data-pk'))}, false);
    };
};
```

html

```
<div>                             
    <img class='image' data-pk='18' src='/site_media/media/img/120x180.jpg'>                             
    <img class='image' data-pk='13' src='/site_media/media/img/007b-300x224.jpg'>                             
    <img class='image' data-pk='15' src='/site_media/media/img/IMG_0549_1.jpg'>                             
</div>
```

Comment: what event is this called in?

Comment: Does this work in other browsers?

Comment: @DanielA.White, it is called on click. I edited my question.

Comment: @AbePetrillo, yes it is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

jQuery can help ... the data attribute works with the data() function in jQuery.

```
$(srcElement).data('pk');
```

You can use it with any data attribute, for example, if you had:

```
<div id="DivId" data-something="foo" data-somethingElse="bar">
```

You can get the data out by:

```
$('#DivId').data('something');
$('#DivId').data('somethingElse');
```

To set data:

```
$('#DivId').data('something', 'foo');
$('#DivId').data('somethingElse', 'bar');
```

Here is a link to [jQuery .data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

**EDIT:**

I think you want:

```
$('.image').click(function () {
    openSlide($(this).data('pk'), false);
});
```

Comment: I did in this way: `open[i].attachEvent('onclick', function(){
        openSlide($(this.srcElement).data('pk'))}, false);` And this is undefined. HTML is ok, data-pk exists. Can't get what I did wrong.

Comment: In the sample, should it be `$('#DivId').data('something');` ?

Comment: Sorry all ... fixed the missing quotes around the data element names

Answer (score 1):

The top answer is outdated. Given the example `<div id="DivId" data-somethingElse="bar"></div>`, you will have to do `$('#DivId').data('somethingelse')` to get the data. The better standard way is to use snake case in HTML, which will yield camelcase in JavaScript:

HTML:

```
<div id="foo" data-something-else="bar"></div>
```

JS:

```
alert($('#foo').data('somethingElse')); // Alerts "bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can use the data method, like this:

```
$(srcElement).data('pk');
```

Note that the string to pass into data is just 'pk', you simply drop the 'data-' part of the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuerys (or other libs) [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) getter. Or you can look into [jQuery source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.3.js) and find out how they achieved cross-browser consistency.